# WCF Data Service - Add Object With Related Object

Tags: windows-phone-7, wcf-data-services

I have the following situation, I have a WCF Data Service with `User` objects and `message` objects and the `message` object has two relations to `user`, a sender and a receiver.

When I try to add a new `Message` object the related users are left null

```
Message message = new Message();
message.text = InputText; // string
message.Sender = Sender; // User object
message.Receiver = Receiver; // User object

context.AddToMessages(message);
context.BeginSaveChanges(new AsyncCallback((result) => 
{ 
    // Some code 
}));
```

Now the Sender and Receiver will be null. When I try to set a link before the `BeginSaceChanges` like this I get the error "InvalidOperationException: The context is not currently tracking the entity."

```
context.AddToMessages(message);
context.AddLink(message, "Sender", message.Sender);
context.AddLink(message, "Receiver", message.Receiver);
context.BeginSaveChanges(new AsyncCallback((result) => 
{ 
    // Some code 
}));
```

How do I make sure the relations are created properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Pratik I found the solution. I had to use attach the already existing users `Sender` and `Receiver` to the context first because they weren't tracked (and added a if if they are on the second call). Then I add the message and use `SetLink` to set the link to both users (instead of `AddLink`)

```
if(context.GetEntityDescriptor(message.Sender) == null)
    context.AttachTo("Users", message.Sender);
if (context.GetEntityDescriptor(message.Receiver) == null)
    context.AttachTo("Users", message.Receiver);
context.AddToMessages(message);
context.SetLink(message, "Sender", message.Sender);
context.SetLink(message, "Receiver", message.Receiver);
context.BeginSaveChanges(new AsyncCallback((result) => 
{ 
    // Some code 
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the `DbSet.Attach` method instead. I assume you use Entity Framework on the back end here.

Comment: You need to add Sender and Receiver object to the context first, before calling AddLink API. Also, since Sender and Receiver are reference properties, you will need to call SetLink API instead of AddLink.